# Heap Sort doesn't work properly

Tags: c, sorting, heapsort

I'm writing sorting application in C for my univesity, and I have a problem with one  algorithm (heap sort). Here is my code:

```
void heap_sort(int *array, int size) {
    int temp;

    heap_build(array, size);

    for(int i = size; i>1; i--) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[1];
        array[1] = temp;
        size--;
        heap_heapify(array, size, 1);
    }
}

void heap_build(int *array, int size) {
    for(int i = size / 2; i > 0; i--)
        heap_heapify(array, size, i);
}

void heap_heapify(int *array, int size, int i) {
    int largest, temp, 
        l = 2 * i, r = (2 * i) + 1;

    if(l <= size && array[l] > array[i])
        largest = l;
    else 
        largest = i;

    if(r <= size && array[r] > array[largest])
        largest = r;

    if(largest != i) {
        temp = array[largest];
        array[largest] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        heap_heapify(array, size, largest);
    }
}
```

The result is for eg:

```
-22
-33686019 // the range is <-100, 100>
-71
-68
-59
-17
-8
43
59
82
```

How you can see, numbers are not sorted properly, and I have one wired number (always in array[1]).

Comment: Have you given the declarations of `heap_build`, `heap_heapify` before their first use? Did you debug your code with prints and/or debugger.

Comment: @MohitJain yes, I have declaration in my *.h file ([see it (ideone)](http://ideone.com/t1JVZ4)). I didn't debug it, I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Now would be a good time to start to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: @PaulR I know how to use it but I don't know what to look for in this algorithm

Comment: show caller side code.

Comment: Well if you know how the algorithm is supposed to work then you can step through the code observing its behaviour and comparing that with your expectations. This is the essence of debugging.

Comment: As a starter you can print the array after first call to function `heap_build(array, size);`, and verify with pen and paper whether it looks like a valid heap to you.

Comment: `if (l <= size)` and `if (r <= size)` looks suspicious in `heapify()`. It looks like you are using only the indexes `1 .. N` in the array, which means that you allocated `N+1` positions, right? So what's the value of `size` that you pass in? Is it `N` or `N+1`?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves `size` is the length of an array (so `n + 1`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/CIkleB)

Comment: your heap sort is not zero origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you mention that you're using array indexes in the interval `1..N` for an array of size `N+1`, but the size you pass in is `N+1`. If that's true, you have an off-by-one error in `max-heapify()`: if `size` is `N+1`, the last position you can access is `N`, not `N+1`, so you must change the comparison to `l < size` (and similarly for `r`):

```
void heap_heapify(int *array, int size, int i) {
    int largest, temp, 
        l = 2 * i, r = (2 * i) + 1;

    if(l < size && array[l] > array[i])
        largest = l;
    else 
        largest = i;

    if(r < size && array[r] > array[largest])
        largest = r;

    if(largest != i) {
        temp = array[largest];
        array[largest] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        heap_heapify(array, size, largest);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your code as close as possible to CLRS, you can use `<=` as long as you pass `N` as the size rather than `N+1` (so, you allocate an array of `N+1` elements, but you pass `N` as the size, so things line up).

[Side note: it has always bugged me that CLRS uses arrays indexed from 1. This always causes trouble when writing real code based on the pseudocode there].

The same happens in `heap_sort()`, either you pass it `N` as size for an array of `N+1` elements or you initialize `i` to `size-1`:

```
void heap_sort(int *array, int size) {
    int temp;

    heap_build(array, size);

    for(int i = size-1; i>1; i--) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[1];
        array[1] = temp;
        size--;
        heap_heapify(array, size, 1);
    }
}
```

Here's a full program with the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void heap_build(int *array, int size);
void heap_heapify(int *array, int size, int i);

void heap_sort(int *array, int size) {
    int temp;

    heap_build(array, size);

    for(int i = size-1; i>1; i--) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[1];
        array[1] = temp;
        size--;
        heap_heapify(array, size, 1);
    }
}

void heap_build(int *array, int size) {
    for(int i = size / 2; i > 0; i--)
        heap_heapify(array, size, i);
}

void heap_heapify(int *array, int size, int i) {
    int largest, temp, 
        l = 2 * i, r = (2 * i) + 1;

    if(l < size && array[l] > array[i])
        largest = l;
    else 
        largest = i;

    if(r < size && array[r] > array[largest])
        largest = r;

    if(largest != i) {
        temp = array[largest];
        array[largest] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        heap_heapify(array, size, largest);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 0, -22, 2, -33, 82, 71, 82, 0, -68, -59, -17, -8, 43, 59, -100 };

    heap_sort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
0
-100
-68
-59
-33
-22
-17
-8
0
2
43
59
71
82
82
```

Note that the first element is never sorted; since you use indexes `1..N`, you're basically ignoring element 0. A quick hack is to pass in a pointer to one element before the start of the array, but that is ugly, and UB (pointer arithmetic is valid only if the resulting pointer references an element in the array, or one past the end).

So I suggest refactoring the code and forget about 1-based indexing. This can be done by adjusting the formulas to calculate the left and right child of a node and adjusting the loop conditions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void heap_build(int *array, int size);
void heap_heapify(int *array, int size, int i);

void heap_sort(int *array, int size) {
    int temp;

    heap_build(array, size);

    for(int i = size-1; i > 0; i--) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[0];
        array[0] = temp;
        size--;
        heap_heapify(array, size, 0);
    }
}

void heap_build(int *array, int size) {
    for(int i = size/2; i >= 0; i--)
        heap_heapify(array, size, i);
}

void heap_heapify(int *array, int size, int i) {
    int largest, temp,
        l = i*2+1, r = l+1;

    if (l < size && array[l] > array[i])
        largest = l;
    else 
        largest = i;

    if (r < size && array[r] > array[largest])
        largest = r;

    if (largest != i) {
        temp = array[largest];
        array[largest] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        heap_heapify(array, size, largest);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 0, -22, 2, -33, 82, 71, 82, 0, -68, -59, -17, -8, 43, 59, -100 };

    heap_sort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The differences from the previous version are:

1. In `heap_sort`, the loop condition turns into `i > 0`.
2. In `heap_build()`, the loop condition turns into `i >= 0`.
3. In `heap_heapify()`, the left child is `2*i+1` rather than `2*i`, and `r` is `2*i+2`.

Comment: now the output is `53
-87
-86
-77
-57
-54
68
72
94
97` so it is pretty close (first element is not sorted) :) I will work on it

Comment: @Davgranded First element is not sorted because you use indexes `1..N`. That's totally expected.

Comment: can you help me, what should I change to work on indexes from 0? I know that this is simple, but I'm so tired becouse of my uni and I cant think :)

Comment: @Davgranded See my updated answer. I refactored the code to use 0-based indexing.

Comment: @Davgranded I also added what I changed in order to make it 0-indexed so that you can understand the differences.